# Springboot yaml properties as map is not working

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using Spring boot 1.5.9. I can not get this simple configuration class to work. What am I missing here?

yaml file:

```
lala:
  jobs:
    foo1: bar
    foo2: bar
  foo: lala
```

Configuration class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "lala", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
@PropertySource("classpath:jobs.yml")
public class Jobs {
    private Map<String, String> jobs = new HashMap<>();
    private String foo;

    public Map<String, String> getJobs() {
        return jobs;
    }

    public void setJobs(Map<String, String> jobs) {
        this.jobs = jobs;
    }

    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Jobs{" +
                "jobs=" + jobs +
                ", foo='" + foo + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I keep getting: `Jobs{jobs={}, foo='null'}`

Comment: How are you initializing the spring `Application` show your `Application.java` class code?! And in your `Jobs` class use  a `prefix` with the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation, like this `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="lala")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can't load YAML the way you're doing it now.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml-shortcomings)

> YAML files can’t be loaded via the `@PropertySource` annotation. So in the case that you need to load values that way, you need to use a properties file.

The main alternative is to use an `application.yml` file instead of a dedicated `jobs.yml` file.  If you must have separation, then your only option is to use a properties file.